# Como otimizar o consumo da memória usando Doctrine

Tags: php, desempenho, memória, doctrine, gerenciamento-de-memória

Preciso ler e salvar no banco de dados dois arquivos o primeiro (menor) tem cerca de 49.000 linhas (cada linha vai ser tornar um registro). Eu faço o parse desse arquivo criando uma instancia para o objeto e então salvo esse objeto no banco de dados usando Doctrine. Eu consigo salvar cerca de 13.000 registros, depois disso o script morre devido a consumo de memória.

Apesar do arquivo ser grande ter mais de 100MB eu não carrego o arquivo todo na memória, eu faço a leitura de uma linha de cada vez. O processo completo da leitura do arquivo, criação de instância, parse e o carregamento de todos os demais dados para o arquivo funcionar (com exceção do Doctrine) em nenhum momento chega a consumir mais que 30 MB (consome menos que 2,5% de ram). Apenas quando executa o Doctrine que o consumo de memória aumenta absurdamente.

Sei que é possível aumentar a quantidade de memória para ser usada alterando as diretivas do php.ini ou usando o ini_set, mas não gostaria dessa solução. O objeto apenas precisa ser gravado no banco de dados e não ficar em memória.

Tentei recuperar os elementos e remover da memória usando o detach:

```
private function clearBatch() {
        $id = $this->last->getId() - 1000;

        $query = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->createQuery(sprintf('SELECT c FROM {MyObjet} c WHERE c.id >= \'%d\'', $id > 0 ? $id : 0));
        $cache = $query->getResult();
        foreach ($cache as $c) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->detach($c);
        }
        $query->free();
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->clear();
        $this->getDoctrine()->resetManager();
        gc_collect_cycles();
    }
```

mas o script sempre morre, acredito que o doctrine está a cada insert armazenando isso em memória, só que eu preciso apenas alimentar o banco de dados com essas informações. Isso não tem necessidade de ficar em memória.

A cada 1000 registros que eu insiro (persist) eu executo o clearBatch

```
public function onProcess($c){
      $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($c);
      $this->count++;
      $this->last = $c;
      if ($this->count % 1000 == 0) {
           $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
           $this->clearBatch();
      }
}
```

tentei até apelar chamando o Garbage Collector.

Se eu não armazenar na persistência consigo ler todos os registros. E o meu consumo de memória é constante (atinge esse pico, logo ao iniciar o script e permanece até o fim) 2.4% (é uma VMWare apenas para teste, tem 1GB de ram), o script morre quando após atingir ~14%.

A função **onProcess** é chamada no loop da leitura do arquivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está justamente no tamanho do arquivo, só contando pelo numero de linhas o arquivo deve ter mais de 50M. Então não tem muito o que fazer seu consumo de memória será alto mesmo.

Eu sugiro duas coisas ou você faz um script só para fazer esse processamento em PHP puro, o consumo ainda vai ser grande mas ai tu consegue otimizar melhor.

Caso queira continuar usando doctrine tenta primeiro ja deixar o entityManager em uma propriedade/variavel ($this->em) de acesso global, inicia no construtor por exemplo, ao invés de sempre dar um $this->getDoctrine->getManager()

Outra coisa tenta usar só o clear na função onProcess

```
public __contruct() {
    //enable gc
    gc_enable();

    //get entityManager
    $this->em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    //disable log (salva um pouco de memoria ao evitar que tudo vá para o log)
    $this->em->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);
}

public function onProcess($c) {

    $this->em->persist($c);
    $this->count++;

    unset($c);

    //diminui um pouco o batch para evitar varios statements
    if ($this->count % 100 == 0) {
         $this->em->flush();
         $this->em->clear(); //detach all objetcs

         gc_collect_cycles();
    }
}
```

Seu método clearBatch só vai deixar o processo mais lento.

Comment: Não há uma forma de tirar da memória a instância usada pelo Doctrine como uma espécie de free nas instâncias já gravadas para que depois o Garbage Collector possa liberar essa memória? Pois realmente o arquivo é grande tem mais de 100MB, mas se eu gerar as instâncias e chamar o onProcess sem utilizar o Doctrine ele usa menos de (2,4%) 30MB para todo o processo, ou seja, apesar dele criar as instâncias, ele libera o espaço. A memória não está sendo sobrecarregada pela leitura do arquivo, pois carrego linha a linha na memória e não o arquivo completo.

Comment: Eu estava usando o clearBatch da forma como você sugeriu, mas adicionei o exemplo completo, pois em outras pesquisas que fiz sugeriram diversas coisas, postei então tudo o que eu já tinha feito, com base em sugestão em pesquisas anteriores. Nenhuma delas surtiu efeito.

Comment: Então o "clear()" é responsável por fazer o "detach" dos objetos

Comment: tenta forçar o gc depois do clear() usando a função gc_collect_cycles(). Você pode tentar ajustar o tamanho do batch também

Comment: Realizei as modificações, mas o consumo continua o mesmo.

Comment: Então acredito que não tenha muito o que fazer, recomendo fortemente fazer essa importação sem o doctrine, como a própria documentação dele fala:

An ORM tool is not primarily well-suited for mass inserts, updates or deletions. Every RDBMS has its own, most effective way of dealing with such operations and if the options outlined below are not sufficient for your purposes we recommend you use the tools for your particular RDBMS for these bulk operations.

Comment: O problema é que o GC só vai liberar a memória se ela estiver marcada para ser liberada, mas acredito que isso não está acontecendo, pois o Doctrine deve estar cacheando isso e ela vai estar em uso. Eu parei nessa documentação também, por questões de portabilidade eu não queria sair do Doctrine.

Comment: ta usando só o doctrine ou ta usando com algum framework tipo o symfony2?

Comment: estou usando o Doctrine com o Symfony2

Comment: vou alterar a resposta veja se ajuda

Comment: Estou rodando o teste, mas com certeza essa deve ser a solução o pico da utilização de memória se fixou em 3,9% (~ 40MB) desde o inicio, contudo eu passei uma informação errada, fui ver não são um pouco mais 49.000 registros, são um pouco mais de 490.000 registros. Assim que terminar eu aviso.

Comment: Muda o texto de sua resposta, pois o código tem uma solução, mas sua resposta leva a crer que não tem solução ou que a solução é outra.

Comment: em todo caso se não der certo e você não quiser fazer um sql puro tenta usar só o DBAL, será mais rápido que o Doctrine

Comment: Vai dar certo, está fixo o consumo em 3,9% e já foram inseridos mais de 350.000 registros.

Comment: Funcionou, consumo máximo 3,9% (~40MB), inseridos 498.825 Registros. Se quiser editar a resposta, me avisa, pois vou fechar a pergunta.